# Convert Objects to List of Objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, object

I'm building an API to add movies to wishlist. I have an endpoint to get all movies in wishlist. My approach was to get the movie ids (not from mongodb) and make an API request to another API to get the movie objects.

This has been successful so far but the problem now is I am getting two objects fused into one object like below:

```
{
   id: 7,
   url: 'https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/7/homeland',
   name: 'Homeland',
   language: 'English',
   genres: [ 'Drama', 'Thriller', 'Espionage' ],  
   status: 'Ended',
   runtime: 60,
   averageRuntime: 60,
   premiered: '2011-10-02',
   officialSite: 'http://www.sho.com/sho/homeland/home',
   schedule: { time: '21:00', days: [ 'Sunday' ] },
   rating: { average: 8.2 },
   image: {
      medium: 'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/230/575652.jpg',
      original: 'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/230/575652.jpg'
   },
  summary: '<p>The winner of 6 Emmy Awards including Outstanding Drama Series, <b>Homeland</b> is an edge-of-your-seat sensation. Marine Sergeant Nicholas Brody is both a decorated hero and a serious threat. CIA officer Carrie Mathison is tops in her field despite being bipolar. The delicate dance these two complex characters perform, built on lies, suspicion, and desire, is at the heart of this gripping, emotional thriller in which nothing short of the fate of our nation is at stake.</p>',
}
```

This is the second object below. Notice how there's no comma separating both objects

```
{
  id: 1,
  url: 'https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/1/under-the-dome',
  name: 'Under the Dome',
  language: 'English',
  genres: [ 'Drama', 'Science-Fiction', 'Thriller' ],
  status: 'Ended',
  runtime: 60,
  averageRuntime: 60,
  premiered: '2013-06-24',
  schedule: { time: '22:00', days: [ 'Thursday' ] },
  rating: { average: 6.6 },
  image: {
     medium: 'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/81/202627.jpg',
     original: 'https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/81/202627.jpg'
  },
  summary: "<p><b>Under the Dome</b> is the story of a small town that is suddenly and inexplicably sealed off from the rest of the world by an enormous transparent dome. The town's inhabitants must deal with surviving the post-apocalyptic conditions while searching for answers about the dome, where it came from and if and when it will go away.</p>",

}
```

My question now is how do I convert both objects to an array and send as a response from my own API. API code is below:

```
module.exports = {
fetchAll: async (req, res, next) => {
  
    var idsArr = [];
    var showsArr;
    var shows;
   
    try {
        let wishlist = await Wishlist.find({});
        if (wishlist == null) {
            res.status(404)
                .json({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'No Movies Found in Wishlist',
                    wishlist: []
                })
        }
        // console.log(wishlist);
        wishlist.map((item) => {
            idsArr.push(item.id);
        })
        console.log(idsArr);
        idsArr.map(async (id) => {
            shows = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${id}`);
            console.log(shows.data);
            // console.log(showsArr);
            // showsArr = [shows.data];
        })
        console.log(showsArr);
        return res.status(200)
                  .json({
                    success: true,
                    msg: 'All Movies in Wishlist Fetched',
                    wishlist: showsArr
                  })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }
},
... // other methods
}
```

I have tried creating an empty array. `shows.data` which is the actual response and then I've tried adding it to my array using `showsArr.push(shows.data)` previously without much success. I get `undefined` when I log to console.

```
Here the ids range from 1 to 240+, in case one wants to try out the endpoint - https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${id}
```

How would I go about achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: What you have in variable "shows", could you give an example? After each interation use a variable to store all shows and see what you have after request, like so, "allShows.push(shows);"  .So, see what you got in allShows

Comment: The variable shows contains the response data from the api call. Could you share a snippet of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like when converting the `wishlist` array to an array of ids, you would need to `push` the data items into your new `showsArr`.

However, this doesn't actually work, since it's asynchronous - you also need to wait for them, using `Promise.all` on an array of promises. And you actually shouldn't be using `push` at all with `map`, [a `map` call already creates an array containing the callback return values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for you. So you can simplify the code to

```
module.exports = {
    async fetchAll(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const wishlist = await Wishlist.find({});
            if (wishlist == null) {
                res.status(404)
                    .json({
                        success: false,
                        msg: 'No Movies Found in Wishlist',
                        wishlist: []
                    })
            }
            const idsArr = wishlist.map((item) => {
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                return item.id;
//              ^^^^^^
            });
            console.log(idsArr);
            const promisesArr = idsArr.map(async (id) => {
                const show = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${id}`);
                console.log(shows.data);
                return shows.data;
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            });
            const showsArr = await Promise.all(promisesArr);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            console.log(showsArr);
            return res.status(200)
                      .json({
                        success: true,
                        msg: 'All Movies in Wishlist Fetched',
                        wishlist: showsArr
                      })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            next(err);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I will need some explanation regarding why you had to assign idsarr.map to a variable and how you were able to identify that it was a Promise. To avoid future mistakes, thank you once again kind sir

Comment: @Nzadibe The `async` function passed to `map()` as a callback returns a promise (for the `return` value), so `map()` returns an array of these promises, that's how `map` works. Assigning it to a temporary variable is not necessary, you can also write `await Promise.all(wishlist.map(async (item) => { … }));` directly.

Comment: I understand it fairly. I'm very glad to have this bit done so far. Much appreciated. Could we have a private chat pls?

Comment: @Nzadibe Anything you want to ask you can [ask as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - link it here and I might have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536341/paginate-array-of-objects-reactjs

Comment: Hello, could you help me answer this question? And this too -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536294/display-search-results-from-api-react-redux. Have your pick sir. Thanks

Comment: Hello sir, I fixed the search issue by removing redux from that part of the app. Thanks for your time. Could you help me with this tiny bit? It's related to one of the answers you gave earlier but I am lacking something to resolve the promises - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568871/resolve-promise-in-nodejs-nested-map-functions-and-return-array-of-objects-from