# Paginate Array of Objects Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have made an API call in my react app, using hooks, redux and thunk and it works perfectly. I am able to display the data in my component.

However, the problem is that the array is too long - 249 objects inside it. I would like to split this array into chunks of 25 objects each and when the user reaches the bottom of the page, fetch the next 25 chunks and so on till the entire list is consumed.

Here's my approach so far:

```
const movies = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.shows)
const searchResults = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.shows);

useEffect(()=> {
    setLoading(true);
    dispatch(fetchAllShows());;
}, [dispatch])

var start, max, paginatedArr=[], pageSize = 25;

for(start = 0; max = movies.length, start < max; start += pageSize) {
    paginatedArr = movies.slice(start, start + pageSize);
}
```

This fetches 25 items from the `movies array` but it doesn't start from the first object. Please how do I rectify this and obtain the use-case I want? Thanks.

Comment: You need to have some kind of state that selects which page of the data you currently display. Then slice the data for that page, in a single call. No looping is necessary.

Comment: I have this function that splits the data into chunks of 25 each. It returns an array of arrays:

Comment: The issue is that I can't loop through it. I understand your perspective above but have no idea how to go about it

Comment: `const res: any = [];
    // const splicedArray = function spliceMovies (arr: any, chunkSize: number) {
    function spliceMovies (arr: any, chunkSize: number) {
        while (arr.length > 0) {
            const chunk = arr.splice(0, chunkSize);
            res.push(chunk);
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    // console.log(splicedArray);

    console.log(spliceMovies(movies, 25));`

Comment: "*It returns an array of arrays*" - well, yes `spliceMovies` does, but the code in your question does not. It just repeatedly overwrite `paginatedArr` with an array, so it ends up with the last chunk from the loop.

Comment: Wow, thanks for clearing that up. How do I access the arrays in `spliceMovies` and display them according to user scrolling behavior, at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: What do you mean by "*according to user scrolling behavior*"? In React, you will need some kind of `const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);`, then after having spliced your movies into  chunks of 25 display then *n*th chunk.

Comment: What I mean't was - I'd try to display the first 25 items in the array and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the first 25 items or first page as one would call it, then the next 25 items from the array are displayed/fetched and so on till the 249 items in the original array have been exhausted/displayed.

Comment: This is called an "infinite scroll", there are many solutions out there. But you don't really need that here since you already *did* fetch all the movies, so just display them all at once. Your API is not paginated.

Comment: What about just paginating the items using `const [page number, setPageNumber] = use state(0);` to do the pagination on the current items. It would require knowing when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page and fetching the next chunks from the paginated array but I'm not entirely sure the best approach to do that.

Comment: Yes, that's how you would need to implement an infinite scroll, but how to detect that the user has scrolled to the bottom should be [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)