# Resolve Promise in Nodejs Nested Map Functions and Return Array of Objects From API Call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to fetch a wishlist from my database. I have saved it in the format:

```
{
    "_id": {
       "$oid": "61006dc65892920d3cadefea"
    },
    "movieId": 240,
    "__v": 0
}
```

where `movieId` is the field I used to save the movies into wishlist. Here's my model class for the above document structure:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const wishlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   movieId: {type: Number},
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model('wishlist', wishlistSchema);
```

In my controller file, to get the total items in wishlist collection, I have tried this approach

```
1. Check if wishlist is empty or not and send response
2. If not empty, get the Object Ids as a list (since the object id represents the totality of the fields in that document)
3. Loop over the object ids list and get the field I'm looking for - movieId field
4. Make an api request to TV Maze api using the movieId, to get the full movie details
5. Send back the list of recovered movie details as response to the user
```

This approach works up till only step 4. I'm stuck with some promises that won't resolve. Here's the message in my console logs:

[image: unresolved promises]

This is the test end point image below, to illustrate what I'm looking to send to the user as response:

[image: Postman Response Format]

Here's the full code for my controller:

```
module.exports = {
fetchAll: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const wishlist = await Wishlist.find({});
        if (wishlist == null) {
            res.status(404)
                .json({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'No Movies Found in Wishlist',
                    wishlist: []
                })
        }

        const objectIds = wishlist.map((item) => item.id);
        
        const showsArr = objectIds.map( async (id) => {
            const moviesFound = await Wishlist.find({'_id': id});

            var shows;

            var data = moviesFound.map( async (movie) => {
                shows = await axios.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${movie.movieId}`);
                return shows.data;
            });
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })

        const wishlistItems = await showsArr;
        console.log(wishlistItems);

        return res.status(200)
                  .json({
                    length: showsArr.length,
                    success: true,
                    msg: 'All Movies in Wishlist Fetched',
                    wishlist: wishlistItems
                  })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        next(err);
    }
},

 .... other methods
}
```

How do I resolve these promises and send back an array of movie item objects to the user? Thanks

Comment: You're missing the `return Promise.all(data)` and `await Promise.all(showsArr)`

Comment: Thanks a ton sir. It worked the only issue now u=is that it converts it to an array of arrays, each containing one object

Comment: Fixed It. Thanks to the amazing community and you in particular sir. Doff my hat, legend